# why when I execute a select it works and when I execute an update the script blocks?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, mariadb, sql

when I try to execute a query of type update the script hangs and the sql console stays still.
This command executes all queries in the script:

```
res=$(mysql --defaults-file=conf_file  --skip-column-names -e "$query")
```

In case I run the following select, it works without any problem and gives me the correct result

```
query="SELECT field FROM table WHERE id=1 and id_ext=1;"
```

but if I execute this update the sql console remains without going on as if I had not put the ; at the end

```
query="UPDATE field SET data=2 WHERE id=1 and id_ext=1;"
```

Comment: I suggest you run it without the `$()` so that you can see what is printed on stdout.  The most likely reason for this hanging is that `mysql` is asking for user input.  It's possible that you need to use `--force` but DO NOT do this until you know what you are forcing it to do.  You can redirect stdin from /dev/null.  `mysql ... < /dev/null`.  So that if it asks for user input it will never hang.

Comment: OK, yes actually adding `</dev/null` works. I did some tests and actually the output of the command was correct, now I'm still trying to understand why it doesn't work. In any case the proposed solution works, thanks!

Comment: You've already been given a suggestion to identify why it didn't work: run the command without using `$(...)` that assigns the result to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the update syntax is correct . General update syntax should be as below

UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET FIELD_NAME = NEW_VALUE
WHERE CONDITION...